# Emgu CV to Detect Circular Cookies on a Baking Sheet

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, hough-transform

I'm fairly new to image processing and that being said, I was hoping someone could tell me if I am on the right track and if not, point me in the right direction and/or provide some code samples.

The requirements I am working on:

- Detect the number of cookies on a baking sheet.
- The cookies can be any color.
- The cookies may be covered in chocolate (white or black) in which case they will have a mess of chocolate around each cookies meaning doing a simple contrast check probably won't work.
- The cookies will not overlap but they may touch one another.

I am trying to use the Emgu CV library with HoughCirlces but I am getting mixed results. Here is my code using winforms and C# in which I load an image of cookies on a baking sheet and run it on (I am not confident in my values).

Am I on the right track? Any ideas? Code samples?

Below are some test images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5qW8.jpg, followed by my code

[image]

[image]

```
private int GetHoughCircles(Image image)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap).Resize(466, 345, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

        //Get and sharpen gray image (don't remember where I found this code; prob here on SO)
        Image<Gray, Byte> graySoft = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray = graySoft.SmoothGaussian(3);
        gray = gray.AddWeighted(graySoft, 1.5, -0.5, 0);

        Image<Gray, Byte> bin = gray.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(149), new Gray(255));

        Gray cannyThreshold = new Gray(150);
        Gray cannyThresholdLinking = new Gray(120);
        Gray circleAccumulatorThreshold = new Gray(50);

        Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges = bin.Canny(cannyThreshold.Intensity, cannyThresholdLinking.Intensity);
        //Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges = bin.Canny(cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);

        //Circles
        CircleF[] circles = cannyEdges.HoughCircles(
            cannyThreshold,
            circleAccumulatorThreshold,
            3.0, //Resolution of the accumulator used to detect centers of the circles
            50.0, //min distance 
            20, //min radius
            30 //max radius
            )[0]; //Get the circles from the first channel

        //draw circles (on original image)
        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            img.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Brown), 2);
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(img.ToBitmap());
        return circles.Count();
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample images?

Comment: Image link added to the post, thanks for the interest!

Comment: This is a pretty tough problem. It is very unlikely that HoughCircles will be able to solve it.  I think I would start by detecting the tray  and removing everything outside of it, detect the paper the biscuits are on and remove it, remove anything small, then you only have the biscuits + some scraps left. But how to separate the remaining biscuits?